# Wallet is not connected to daemon

Tags: daemon

I am a total beginner setting up my Monero wallet.  I am also very limited with computer knowledge.  I was able to download the Mac OS X 64bit.  At this point I have read and tried a number of articles on "Wallet is not connected to daemon".  I have not been able to locate any folder or files with an exe.file.  I have tried using "simple mode" and "advanced mode" to get the wallet to sync with a node with no luck.  Frankly I'm not even sure I am saying things correctly?

Comment: Do you run AV (AntiVirus) software on your Mac? With respect to showing the 'daemon' component, you have to right click on `monero-wallet-gui.app` -> `Show Contents`. `monerod` should then appear.

Comment: Thanks ... I'll look at this once I get home tonight

Comment: That was very helpful as I was able to see code (?) .  I get this message: E Error locking fd45: 35 (Resource temporarily unavailable) E Failed to lock /Users/xxxx/Monero/wallets/xxxxx/xxxx.keys: resource temporarily unavailable.  E  !is_keys_file_locked(). Throw exception:  errors: :wallet-internal_error.  Error opening wallet:  internal error.  Honestly I don't know what this means or how to correct the errors.  Thanks for any help someone offers.

Comment: Could you try to connect your wallet to a remote node first? https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#remote-node

Answer (score 0):

If you have low technical knowledge, I would recommend looking into using a more user-friendly wallet like Feather (https://featherwallet.org/) for desktop or Cake Wallet (https://cakewallet.com/) for mobile.

I can't help fix the issue very much given the information you've provided. Simple mode in the GUI wallet should connect to a remote node after you've signed into the wallet.

Comment: When trying to connect in simple mode; I still get the same note: "Wallet is not connected to daemon"?  Thanks for trying to help me.